# Facebook apps not displaying unless logged in

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I have developed some iframe apps for a companies Facebook page (https://www.facebook.com/CresserMotorGroup). Unfortunately the app pages don't work unless you're logged into Facebook.

I've checked the app settings and can't seem to find anything that would cause this.

Is this intentional?

Thanks.

Comment: what is not working? Are you referring to the fact if user is not signed into Facebook and they click on "Current Stocklist" page app, nothing shows up?

Comment: Yeah. Sorry I should have said. The Stocklist, New Vehicle Offers and the How to Find Us all just hang when not logged in.

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but it doesn't work even if you're signed in. Error: `Error 111 (net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED): Unknown error.` HRF: `The webpage at https://www.cresser.co.uk/facebook/stocklist/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.` Looks like a server problem, since HTTPS isn't working, but HTTP is.

Comment: So, in the development screen when is asks for a Canvas URL/Page Tab URL and a Secure Canvas URL/Secure Page Tab URL, it's these secure URL it would try to use when not logged in? I've not got a secure socket setup on my server due to cost. If this is the case, why would Facebook do this?

Comment: Well, you can still use it without the Secure URL (HTTPS), but you will always get a warning about visiting a non-secure URL when visiting from **https**://www.facebook.com (maybe even when from http - not sure). You can try it and you'll see.

Comment: well, this is the reason Facebook is requiring secure canvas url: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/452/

Comment: Thanks guys. Guess it's back to the drawing board for me.